# Selecting a value from a discrete probability distribution if another column = 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, probability

I am for all intents and purposes a complete newbie when it comes to SQL and I am attempting to perform a certain task but I have no idea how to go about it.

I have a table (lets call it **A**) where I have a column 'Claims Made', which has a binary variable (0/1) and a corresponding column 'Claim Amount' column. If 'Claims Made' is 1, I wished to pull a value for 'Claim Amount' from another table (lets call it **B**) where one has determined a discrete probability distribution for said claim amount (where the probability is in column x, and the amount in column y). I wished to pull the values in such a way that the distribution of the values in 'Claim Amount' in **A**, matches with the probabilities given in table **B**.

My apologies for not providing any pseudo code but I have no idea how to go about this task.

In essence for **A**  I have the columns:

```
+-------------+-------+--------+
| Observation | Claim | Amount |
+-------------+-------+--------+
| 1           | 1     |        |
| 2           | 1     |        |
| 3           | 0     |        |
| 4           | 0     |        |
| ...         | ...   |        |
| 99          | 1     |        |
```

and for **B** I have the columns:

```
+---------------------+
| | Prob  | Amount |  |
+---------------------+
| |0.2407 | 2750   |  |
| |0.1543 | 1250   |  |
| |0.1296 | 3250   |  |
| |0.1420 |12500   |  |
| |0.0494 | 3250   |  |
| |0.0309 | 72500  |  |
| |0.1358 | 2250   |  |
| |0.0247 | 4500   |  |
| |0.0617 | 5500   |  |
| |0.0309 | 1750   |  |
+---------------------+
```

Ideally the distribution of values in **A** should match the probabilities in **B**. I.e. for 10000 observations (where claim = 1), 2407 cells for Amount should be 2750. So in **A** I should have:

```
+-------------+-------+--------+
| Observation | Claim | Amount |
+-------------+-------+--------+
| 1           | 1     |2750    |
| 2           | 1     |1250    |
| 3           | 0     |0       |
| 4           | 0     |        |
| ...         | ...   |        |
| 99          | 1     |3250    |
```

for example.

I am using SQLserver if that helps at all.

Many Thanks.

Comment: you probably need to JOIN A to B using the key that links A to B (you need to look at how you choose the record from table B given a record from A).  As for the probability calculation, I don't think there is enough info for us to follow.  We could do  with some tables and data, plus an explanation of the basis of the calculation

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  For instance, how is a discrete probability distribution represented in your tables?

Comment: Hi All, I've added some sample data. I kept it to 99 observations for simplicity).

Comment: There still is insufficient information I'm afraid, what is the unique identifier in Table B, are these all of the columns?

Comment: shawkins, in effect there is no unique identifier i simply desire to have (if I have 10,000 observations of Claim = 1 in **A**)  2407 samples of 2750, 1543 of 1250 and so on.